# Regular Expressions are marked as Security Hotspot on SonarQube report

Tags: regex, spring-boot, sonarqube

Why following expression `"Test--[A-Z]{3}_[0-9]{1,2}[MYD]{1}"` is considered as Security Hotspot in SonarQube report?

Shall we mark this as "Resolve as reviewed"? or we have some other workaround?

[image]

Comment: As per (https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/type/Security%20Hotspot/RSPEC-4784), the warning is because of possible vulnerabilities with RegEx evaluation engine. If possible, you can use Google Re2.

Answer (score 1):

You can mark it as reviewed and safe to use.

The `Test--[A-Z]{3}_[0-9]{1,2}[MYD]{1}` pattern is equal to `Test--[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]_[0-9][0-9]?[MYD]`.

For a regex to be an evil regex, there must be a considerable backtracking possibility that is only possible with `*`, `*?`, `+`, `+?` and `{x,}` / `{x,}`? like quantifiers in non-final position inside the pattern.

Yours is an example of a pattern where only the one or two digit pattern can get backtracked into, but there is just two possible ways to match the pattern, which is not problematic and does not present any threat.

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me mark as reviewed and explore on the expression Test--[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]_[0-9][0-9]?[MYD]